# JavaFX Event Dispatching thread vs. JavaFX Application Thread?

Tags: java, javafx-8, event-dispatch-thread

I'm wondering if the JavaFX Application Thread is the same as the event dispatching thread? I know JavaFX Application `Thread` is used for:

1. manage/update scene graph node trees
2. process non-blocking UI events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no special JavaFX Event Dispatching thread. Just the JavaFX Application Thread.